# Change the "default value " in a column with mysqlWorkbench

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

I'm searching for how to apply the change of the default value in a column using mysqlworkbench. It's really easy with phpadmin.
So far I can do it only by updating the statement.
Do you know how to change the value visually like phpadmin with mysqlworkbench?

[image: Mysql Workbench]
[Full size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhGDZ.png)

Comment: It's been a long time since I last used workbench, but did you try right clicking on the column? the edit menu? Have you looked on [workbench's help pages](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-edit-menu.html)? Why don't you use [Adminer](http://www.adminer.org/) instead of phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this from the table action menu:

1. Select the table
2. Right click to show the commands
3. Select "Alter table ..."
4. After making the necessary changes, click "Apply"

Answer (score 2):

Right click and select "Alter table.."

You can then set the "Default" value for specific field

Remember to save the changes by clicking the "Apply" button after setting the default value.
[image]

Comment: In the current version (or my resolution), you only see the top part of the screen above. You need to hit the two arrowheads on the top right hand corner to expand and see your columns.